# How to get Intellisense on a generic View method in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, intellisense

In the MVC frameworks the Controller has a method named `View(string viewPath, object model)`.
I created a derived class of `MyController : Controller`.

so what i am trying to achieve is a new method with generic that the model is typed like so
`View<T>(string viewPath,T model)`. 
My question is can i have the same intellisense functionality as the base `View()` method ?
Meaning - painting it red if the viewPath does not linked to a view (aspx,ascx, cshtml file), marking it with an underscore if it does ?

Thank you

Comment: Showing what red if what doesn't exist?

Comment: If the view does not exist (you haven't created the view that the path represents)

Comment: Seems like you are using Resharper or any other extension that does that trick. I don't believe you can achieve this for a custom method.

Comment: @Zabavsky i thought it was a basic VS intellisense feature, I've been using resharper for so long i can't see the difference any more. i'll give it a look

Comment: @Zabavsky - you were correct, boy do i feel like an ass :)